# Red body glow on TSA cat scan

Tags: tsa

Every time my 87 year old mother goes through a TSA scan, her body glows red on the screen and she has to be patted down. Why would her body glow red? (The agent showed me her screen)

Comment: [This article](https://www.rd.com/article/what-do-airport-body-scanners-see/) has a few examples for possible false positives. If it covers a lot of her body, it might just be related to sweat, but there are lots of other possibilities. I know a single packet of tissues in your packet can trigger it.